# VLOOKUP against helper column with date formatted as text?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm using a vlookup against a table that has a generally-formatted column in the format "WORD NUMBER DATE" such as "Romeo 5M 06/16/2019". The reference is a helper column that I've created combining "Romeo" and "5M" and "06/16/2019". However, the date part needs to be formatted as text or else it won't match the lookup. This formatting is causing the #N/A error, despite a match. When I use =cell=cell2, it brings up "FALSE", given the formatting.

Help with this?

Thanks in advance.

I've already tried copy/paste formatting, and typing out the text in the cell makes the reference work so I'm assuming it's the formatting.

Comment: Would help to show some example data and the lookup formula you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date in three separate cells.  Assuming your date is in cell A1:

In Cell B1 - get the Year value

```
=YEAR(A1)
```

In Cell C1 - change the value to 2 digits if the month value is only 1:

```
=IF(LEN(MONTH(A1)) = 1, "0" & MONTH(A1), MONTH(A1))
```

In Cell D1 - change the value to 2 digits if the day value is only 1:

```
=If(LEN(DAY(A1)) = 1, "0" & DAY(A1), DAY(A1))
```

Then, in your aggregation formula, combine them like this:

```
= C1 & "/" & D1 & "/" & B1
```

If I'm reading your question correctly this should solve your issue.

Alternatively, if you need to change the cell format to text you may need to use vba code to perform some calculations for you which I can outline for you as well if this solution doesn't help you.